# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for (I believe this is UINavigationController related)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

It looks like this topic comes up a lot. I read through several answers but none were the same case as mine so please excuse me if you've seen similar before.

All of my UIViewControllers are being controlled by UINavgationController. On the first UIViewController (SMOnboardingPhotoMarketingViewController), I call into my keychain wrapper class to see if there is anyone logged in (app resuming). If so I call the segue to go to my main logged in screen (SMThumbnailViewController), where I'm getting the error message: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

I have examined all of the view controller life-cycle calls to ensure that I'm calling [super method] if I over-rode them. Done.

Other than that this is just a standard push type segue for all transitions. I don't understand what is so different about this call to a segue than all the others that are triggered by button actions. Here is the code from my first view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self loadScrollViewContent];

    __weak SMOnboardingPhotoMarketingViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [SMAuthentication validateStoredTokenWithCompletion:^(BOOL valid) {
        if(valid){
            NSLog(@"Logged in. Continue to thumbs page");
            [weakSelf performSegueWithIdentifier:kSeguePhotoMarketingToThumbnails sender:self];
        }
        else{
            [SMAuthentication logOut];
            NSLog(@"invalid credentials stored. User must log in ");
        }
    }];
}
```

I've noticed that in my main view controller (the one that the above code navigates to), viewDidLoad is called, but viewDidAppear is never called. What could cause such an imbalance?

Edit: Adding info. I should state taht if I move the segue call to the outside of that block, the transition goes as normal with no error. Example:

```
// I know this is ugly. It is for testing only
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self loadScrollViewContent];
    __block BOOL complete = NO;
    __block BOOL isValid = NO;

    [SMAuthentication validateStoredTokenWithCompletion:^(BOOL valid) {
        if(valid){
            NSLog(@"Logged in. Continue to thumbs page");
            isValid = YES;
        }
        else{
            [SMAuthentication logOut];
            NSLog(@"invalid tokens stored. User must log in ");
        }
        complete = YES;
    }];



    while (!complete) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

    if(isValid){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSeguePhotoMarketingToThumbnails sender:self];
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like my SMAuthenticate call is calling the completion block twice would make sense given the errors. That's another story however.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have implemented the following ViewController custom container methods:

```
- (void)endAppearanceTransition
- (void)beginAppearanceTransition:(BOOL)isAppearing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

I once written and forgot them in a base class and they messed up the whole appearance forwarding to child controllers when using storyboards.